# Eclipse - project imported to Windows from Linux not loading resources

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, project

I've created a project on Linux that uses various resources (.png and .xml) that are successfully loaded when I run the code on Linux but once I've exported the project to Windows it throws Null Pointer Exceptions when I try to do the same thing.

Exporting/importing was done through the archive file mechanism and I've also tried manually importing source files, creating folders and importing resource files into them. The folder structure seems intact and the resource folder is marked as a source folder on both platforms as it should be.

Instead of hard-coding file separators I've used the system-dependent ones so there shouldn't be a problem regarding that.

Misc. info: Linux Mint 32-bit/Windows 7 64-bit, Eclipse with WindowBuilder, Java 1.7 (on both platforms)

An example of resource loading:

```
public static void loadGameImages(TreeMap<String, ImageIcon> imageMap)
    {
        String dir_path = GameMechanics.class.getResource(
                File.separator + "gameImages").toString(); // this is where the whole thing breaks
        URI uri = null;
        try
        {
            uri = new URI(dir_path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            raiseError(ex);
        }

        File dir = new File(uri.getPath());
        File[] images = null;
        if (dir.isDirectory())
            images = dir.listFiles();
        for (File f : images)
        {
            if (f.isFile())
                imageMap.put(f.getName(), new ImageIcon(f.getPath()));
        }
    }
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hangman.GameMechanics.loadGameImages(GameMechanics.java:98)
    at hangman.MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.java:90)
    at hangman.MainWindow$1.run(MainWindow.java:65)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: And where exactly is your gameImages directory?

Comment: @JunedAhsan It is inside the "resources" folder. Everything was added through Eclipse, not directly through the file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.getResource()` won't accept a backslash as a separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

You need to change:

```
File.separator + "gameImages"
```

to:

```
"/gameImages"
```

More generally, the path separator in URIs (and URLs are a subset of URIs) is `/` and never `\`.

Addendum: since you use Java 1.7, drop `File`, use the new `Files` API.

Comment: That was it, thank you. Won't drop File though - if it ain't broke,  don't fix it! ;)

Comment: But the `File` API _is_ broken (what about `FileNotFoundException` when, in fact, the problem is that you cannot access the file?). Believe me, use `Files`.

Comment: It works just fine with the solution you suggested and besides, this isn't a "serious" project. Anyway, I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1):

in Java the libraries which dealing with files, you can safely use /  on all platforms. so you can call it like this `GameMechanics.class.getResource("/gameImages").toString();`